# Error en Link tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs, enlace, routerlink

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][![Usando la etiqueta Link en el componente donde la importo(NavBar) funciona correctamente, pero al importar NavBar component en el componente Home, y usando la navegación de Link, me da un error y al recargar me lleva al lugar donde apunta '[![Home component, el error es: Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: destroy is not a function

Call Stack
safelyCallDestroy
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (19747:0)
commitHookEffectListUnmount
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (19929:0)
commitHookPassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22564:0)
commitPassiveUnmountInsideDeletedTreeOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22764:0)
commitPassiveUnmountEffectsInsideOfDeletedTree_begin
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22720:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22582:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22643:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22610:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22643:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22643:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22643:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22643:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22610:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22643:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22610:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22610:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22643:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22610:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22643:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22643:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22643:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22643:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22643:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22610:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22643:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22610:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22610:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)
commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22610:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveUnmountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22596:0)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZc3N.png)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZc3N.png)href'][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVV2d.png)][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVV2d.png)

Comment: Hola Wilson, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código y los mensajes de error (si es que los recibes) en formato texto, y que nos expliques en que falla, mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!

Comment: Este error muchas veces está relacionado a `useEffect`s, comparte el código que esté haciendo use de `useEffect`s.